# SQL Server : Security User Login

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our WMS uses a database `TSECURE` to handle all logins from our WMS. I am thinking of creating my own new software for upload purposes only. In this tsecure we maintain / add different security user logins for different users. For example, I must create a WMS Access for `Alex`, I will create first a SQL Server login for `alex`, then add his [wms_user + wms_pass] to `[TSECURE]` with DB credentials under `[sql_server_user_alex / pass]`.

**My questions:**

- Is it necessary to use different security logins for different users?
- Would it be OK to just use a single user for all of them? ex. `userS: [alex1] / [joseph2] / [jdoe] / [aron] ...` are all under `[sa]` security login? What would be the downside of this?

Comment: The normal approach for this would be: (1) create a **Windows group**, (2) put your three users into that group, (3) create a SQL Server login for that group, and (4) give that group login the necessary permissions in your database. That way, you can add new members to that Windows group and they'll automatically have all the necessary permissions to access that database. **Don't --EVER-- use the `sa` account** in a production system! **NO exceptions!**

Comment: Ok... What if I dont use SA, I use a user named: wms. Can I use this user? Like I would embed the db connection of wms/pass to the connection string. Then I will create my own table for Users. They will all share the same DB connection under [wms]. Will that be OK?

Comment: Yes, a custom "application user" can be OK. But as long as you are in a Windows intranet environment - why not use the Windows accounts directly? Setting up a Windwos group for something like this is the preferred and easiest way to go, really

Comment: what do you mean use Windows Accounts Directly? Kindly elaborate please. Our network is using a Domain. Do you mean a user can just use his domain user password to connect to the database?

Answer (score 1):

As marc_s noted.

> The normal approach for this would be: (1) create a Windows group, (2) put your three users into that group, (3) create a SQL Server login for that group, and (4) give that group login the necessary permissions in your database. That way, you can add new members to that Windows group and they'll automatically have all the necessary permissions to access that database. Don't --EVER-- use the sa account in a production system! NO exceptions!

[Windows Authentication is much more secure than SQL Authentication.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx)

"Putting all users under SA" - do not do this under any context.

[Please review the CIS SQL Server baseline for further guidance.](https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/sqlserver/CIS_Microsoft_SQL_Server_2014_Benchmark_v1.0.0.pdf)